# Passing JavaScript variable to PHP through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am following the guide from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp, and I get the basic concept of how this works.

My code:

### PHP:

```
<?php
include('./db.php');
$PM = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT PMName FROM report WHERE PMname <> '' ORDER BY PMName ASC");
?>
<select class="navbar-inverse" placeholder="PM Name" name="PMName"onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($PM)) {
$selected = array_key_exists('PMName', $_POST) && $_POST['PMName'] == $row[0] ? ' selected' : '';
printf(" <option value='%s' %s>%s</option>\n", $row[0], $selected, $row[0]);
}
?>
</select>
<div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

### JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str !==".PM") {
        alert(str);
        if (str=="") {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

### and the getuser.php page:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
include('./db.php');
$sqlPM= "SELECT * FROM report WHERE PMName = '".$q."'";
$result     = mysqli_query($con, $sqlPM);
?>

<table>
<?php
echo $q ;
?>
</table>
```

I have read through about 12 posts here and tried to make sense of the fact that most of these use some form of `$.post('getuser.php'`to send the variable over to the new PHP page, but the example from w3schools does not do this.  On the initial page, my dropdown is populating fine from my database, and the value I select is being passed into the JavaScript function.  I check this with `alert(str);`, but from there, it doesn't ever seem to get to the second PHP page.  I tried testing that it came over using `echo $q ;`, but that comes up as empty.

What am I doing wrong that is causing the variable that the JavaScript function captures to not be passed over to the second PHP page?

From what I can see, I am following the instructions on the tutorial just fine.

Comment: `$.post('getuser.php'` This syntax is exclusive to a javascript library called `jQuery`. Furthermore, `$q` is not an `integer` it is a `string` considering the DB query you perform initially, so why are you wrapping `$_GET['q']` with `intval()`?

Comment: Perfect!  I wasn't familiar with `intval` or its purpose, but this makes sense.  It was in there because that's what the tutorial said, but yes, this is definitely a string.  I took this out and the code works beautifully now.  Thank you @Ohgodwhy  .  I wish I could upvote you or something but I don't have enough reputation. :(

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I suggest you put in an answer using the exact comment you wrote, just so we can close the question. Will +1 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.post('getuser.php'` This syntax is exclusive to a javascript library called `jQuery`. Furthermore, `$q` is not an `integer` it is a `string` considering the DB query you perform initially, so why are you wrapping `$_GET['q']` with `intval()`?

Comment: I realized why the code in the tutorial came over like this.  Their initial example used `<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>` in their example, so they wrapped the response in `intval`.  Either way, thank you so much for your help!